# Estimating the probability of getting an a rental based on a series of waitlists

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is more of a thought experiment but I am trying to formulate a clean estimate that takes into account several things when estimating the probability of getting an a rental based on a series of waitlists.

Let $p_o$ be the probability of event $o$, an apartment becoming available. Consequently, ${p_o}^{n_{0}}$ is the probability of $n_0$ apartments will become available.

Apartments operate on the basis of a waitlist with $w$ people in it. Therefore the event getting an apartment based on the waitlist is:
$$
p = {p_o}^{n_{0}} * n_0/w
$$

where $n_0 \leq w$ and $w \ne 0$.

If a person manages to get in $x$ waitlists, then the probability of getting an apartment is
$$
1-(1-p)^x
$$

I have two questions based on the above:

- Is what I described correct based on the input variables which are $w,p_0,x,n_0$? Any more elegant ways of expressing this?
- The current solution requires me that I declare the estimate number of apartments that may become available ($n_0$) to calculate $p$. Yet, I feel that there must be a away to use the $p_0$ to estimate all possible $n_0$ variants ($1,2,3,...z$) resulting in an general $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the probability of $n$ apartments becoming available is not $p_0^{n_0}$.
If you consider a population of $N$ apartments, and each (independently) has probability $p_0$ of becoming available in a given time period, then the 
probability that exactly $n$ of them become available is ${N \choose n} p^n (1-p)^{N-n}$.

You appear to be describing a lottery system  rather than what I would call a wait list.  That is, if there are $w$ people on the list and $n < w$ apartments become available, then $n$ people on the list will be chosen at random to get an apartment. There is also a possibility that not all of these lucky people will accept the offer of an apartment because they have already found accommodation elsewhere, but I'll ignore that.  Then indeed the conditional probability of getting an apartment, given that $n<w$ become available, is $n/w$.  If $n \ge w$, that conditional probability is $1$.  Thus the total probability of getting one of these apartments is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{w-1} \frac{n}{w} {N \choose n} p_0^n (1-p_0)^{N-n} + \sum_{n=w}^N {N \choose n} p_0^n (1-p_0)^{N-n} $$

Comment: Excellent response! A few additional comment/questions. So, the probability that at least 1 or more apartments may become available is: $1 - (\binom{N}{0} * p^0 * (1-p)^{N-0}) = 1-(1-p)^N$. Correct?
Actually, it was the idea of a waitlist, for example, if 1 becomes available and there 5 people on the list then 1/5 is the only correct combination (position) that grants you the apartment. Shouldn't then, the probability of an apartment becoming available times 1/5 result in the probability of getting the apartment?

Comment: Actually, I realized my previous comment was wrong. Running the last equation that you have provided I think it accurately estimates at least the probability based on random picks out of the waitlist. Just so that I am sure I understand correctly: The first sum, estimates the added probabilities of all possible outcomes for $n = 0$ to $n < w$ based on a waitlist probability(factor $n/w$), while the second estimates the probabilities for $n>w$ for which there wont be a waitlist (hence factor of 1).